# explicacion sobre el codigo de una funcion JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Buen dia. Sucede que he querido aprender a crear modales usando solo HTML, CSS y JavaScript sin el uso de ningún framework o librería. He visto algunos métodos, pero me gustó mucho este, es bastante útil y adaptable. El punto es que he estado leyendo este código y hay una parte que no entiendo(código Js) y es la parte de los if en la función createCustomElement(la segunda función), el código esta comentado con la zona de las dudas y cuales son. Les agradecería enormemente si me regalan una explicación clara de esa parte. Fuente: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=86f4Qf0gxjo

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>probando el modal de Edteam</title>

  <style>
    .ed-modal-container {
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
      position: fixed;
      top: 10px;
      width: 100%;
      margin-left: -0.5rem;
      height: 100vh;
      display: flex;
    }
    
    .ed-modal-container::before {
      position: absolute;
      content: "X";
      color: #ffffff;
      top: 1rem;
      right: 1rem;
      font-size: 2rem;
    }
    
    .ed-modal-content {
      background: #ffffff;
      width: 90%;
      max-width: 1000px;
      margin: auto;
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<!--Codigo HTML-->

<body>
  <h1 id="show-modal">Presione aca para mostrar el modal</h1>
</body>

<script>
  //Añadir un objetivo de atributos a un elemento
  const addAttributes = (element, attrObj) => {
    for (let attr in attrObj) {
      if (attrObj.hasOwnProperty(attr)) element.setAttribute(attr, attrObj[attr])
    }
  };
  //Crear elemento con atributos e hijos (inician las dudas)
  const createCustomElement = (element, attributes, children) => { //no me queda muy claro el manejo del parametro "children"
    let customElement = document.createElement(element);
    if (children !== undefined) children.forEach(el => { //"children !== undefined" quiere decir, si existe un hijo?
      if (el.nodeType) { //no me queda claro 
        if (el.nodeType === 1 || el.nodeType === 11) //y mi mayor duda es esta parte
          customElement.appendChild(el); //aca algo de duda tengo
      } else {
        customElement.innerHTML += el;
      }
    });
    addAttributes(customElement, attributes);
    return customElement;
  }
  //imprimir modal
  const printModal = (content) => {
    //crear contenedor interno
    const modalContentEl = createCustomElement("div", {
      id: "ed-modal-content",
      class: "ed-modal-content"
    }, [content])
    //crear contenedor principal
    const modalContainerEl = createCustomElement("div", {
      id: "ed-modal-container",
      class: "ed-modal-container"
    }, [modalContentEl]);

    //imprimir modal
    document.body.appendChild(modalContainerEl)

    //Remover el modal
    const removeModal = () =>
      document.body.removeChild(modalContainerEl);

    modalContainerEl.addEventListener("click", e => {
      console.log(e);
      if (e.target === modalContainerEl) removeModal();
    })
  }[introducir la descripción del enlace aquí][1]

  let showModal = document.getElementById("show-modal");
  showModal.addEventListener("click", () => {
    printModal(`<h1>aprendiendo a crear modales con js</h1>`)
  })
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: ¿Qué exactamente no entiendes?

Comment: el codigo js esta comentado a la derecha con las dudas. Las dudas son sobre la funcion createCustomElement.

Comment: Parece ser un problema que no se puede reproducir.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tal y como menciona el video en el minuto 4:30, la función `createCustomElement` sirve para evitar la tarea repetitiva de crear elementos, asignarles atributos e insertarles contenido.

Básicamente, es una abstracción para que esto:

```javascript
var content = 'Hola!';

var nuevoDiv = document.createElement("div"); 

var idElemento = document.createAttribute("id");
idElemento.value = 'ed-modal-content';
nodo.setAttributeNode(a);

var claseElemento = document.createAttribute("class");
claseElemento.value = 'ed-modal-content';
nodo.setAttributeNode(a);

var elementoContenido = document.createTextNode(content); 
nuevoDiv.appendChild(newContent);
```

Se convierta en esto:

```javascript
var content = 'Hola!';
const modalContentEl = createCustomElement("div", {
    id: "ed-modal-content", 
    class: "ed-modal-content"
}, [content])
```

En cuanto al mecanismo interno de la función:

```javascript
    const createCustomElement = (element, attributes, children) => {
    // Función para crear un nuevo elemento, el cual se almacenará en la variable "customElement".
    // El parámetro attributes contiene un arreglo asociativo que se agregarán como atributos al elemento que estamos creando.
    // El parámetro children es un arreglo que contiene cadenas de texto, u otros tipos de nodo HTML.
    // En la siguiente URL puedes consultar los distintos tipos de nodos que existen
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType#Node_type_constants

        let customElement = document.createElement(element);

        if (children !== undefined) children.forEach(el => {
            // La condición (children !== undefined) actúa como una validación, para asegurarnos de que hemos recibido el parámetro y que contiene algo
            if( el.nodeType ) {
                // En esta validación comprobamos si el parámetro que recibimos es un nodo HTML. Bien podría ser un número o simplemente una cadena de texto, los cuales no tendrían la propiedad propiedad "nodeType".
                if(el.nodeType === 1 || el.nodeType === 11)
                customElement.appendChild(el);
                // En esta parte, comprueba que el tipo de nodo sea uno u once, antes de anexarlo al elemento padre (La variable customElement).
                // Como nota adicional, puesto que sólo se ejecuta una instrucción no es necesario poner llaves {} después de la sentencia if, como se acostumbra.
            }else{
                // Si el elemento no es un nodo HTML, sencillamente lo concatenamos al contenido del elemento que estamos creando.
                customElement.innerHTML += el;
            }
        });
        // Esta siguiente línea es para agregar los atributos que recibe la función como segundo parámetro.
        addAttributes(customElement, attributes);
        // Esta siguiente línea retorna el elemento creado, con el contenido agregado y los atributos asignados.
        return customElement;
    }
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, explicas muy bien. Creo que mejor explicado no pudo haber quedado.